# Adding next element in list if previous already added

Tags: python, list, if-statement, append, iteration

I would like to append the next element from a list, if present in another list, from a certain element on and so on.
I' ll explain further: I have these 2 lists

```
numb_5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
numb = [3, 1, 6, 4, 7, 8, 5, 1, 2]
```

I would like to append to a new list the first `len(numb_5)` elements of `numb` that appear in `numb_5` and if an element doesn' t appear in `numb_5`, append the first element of `numb` after `len(numb_5)` and so on, of course not the same element **as appears to be my problem** (from `numb`, instead of 6 the result must store 5 and instead of 7 it should store 1). I hope that with my **wrong** code, the explanation will be clearer:

```
result = []
for n in numb[:len(numb_5)]:
    if n in numb_5:
        result.append(n)
    else:
        count = 1
        if numb[len(numb_5)+count] in numb_5:
            result.append(numb[len(numb_5)+count])
        else:
            count += 1
```

I think I get the problem is in the last else statement, because *result* stores 5 instead of moving on and storing 1, but anyhow can' t solve it.
Obtained result from my wrong code: `result = [3, 1, 5, 4, 5]`
Requested result should be: `result = [3, 1, 5, 4, 1]`

I am very thankful to whoever can help me out!

Comment: I think your code is almost correct, please move `count = 1` to the very top of the snippet

Comment: Nope, unfortunately still doesn' t give a correct result. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drawing a flowchart or otherwise planning out your code really helps, so let's give that a shot.

1. We have `numb_5 = [...]`, `numb = [...]` and we know that `len(numb) > len(numb_5)`
2. Let's separate our "primary selection" and "secondary selection" into separate arrays to make life easier

   - `numb_pri = numb[0:len(numb_5)]`
   - `numb_sec = numb[len(numb_5):]`
3. Let's also make `numb_5 = set(numb_5)` to make membership checks faster
4. Now we might as well get rid of the numbers in `numb_sec` that aren't in `numb_5`, since we don't want them anyway.
5. Make an empty `result = []` list
6. As we iterate over each element `e` of `numb_pri`:

   1. Is `e` in `numb_5`?

      - Yes? Add `e` to `result`
      - No? Pull the first element of `numb_sec` and add *that* to `result`

        - No more elements in `numb_sec` to pull? *Figure out how to handle this case!!!* Maybe we can just fall back to add `e` to `result`?
7. Go to the next `e`

As code:

```
numb_pri = numb[0:len(numb_5)]
numb_sec = numb[len(numb_5):]

numb_5 = set(numb_5)

# Getting rid of useless elements of numb_sec
numb_sec = [x for x in numb_sec if x in numb_5]

result = []

for e in numb_pri:
    if e in numb_5: # e is in numb_5
        result.append(e) # Push e into result
    else:
        if numb_sec: # numb_sec isn't empty
            x = numb_sec.pop(0) # Remove the first element of numb_sec into x
            result.append(x)    # Push x into result
        else: # numb_sec is empty
            result.append(e) # Fallback: Push e into result

print(result)
```

Which gives us the output:

```
[3, 1, 5, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Is it possible to do so without removing elements? I need it for colums of data, that removing elements of which would mess up indices.

Comment: We made a copy in step 2, so the original list is going to be unchanged